# How to generate alerts on grafana dashboards using python

Tags: python, linux, grafana

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py"
> line 565, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='none', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/ruler/grafana/api/v1/rules/testfolder/Production%20Alerts (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7feb3b36b910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))"

These are the codes that I tried

```
from grafanalib.core import AlertGroup
from grafanalib._gen import DashboardEncoder, loader
import json
import requests
from os import getenv


def get_alert_json(alert: AlertGroup):
    '''
    get_alert_json generates JSON from grafanalib AlertGroup object

    :param alert - AlertGroup created via grafanalib
    '''

    return json.dumps(alert.to_json_data(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, cls=DashboardEncoder)


def upload_to_grafana(alertjson, folder, server, api_key, session_cookie, verify=True):
    '''
    upload_to_grafana tries to upload the AlertGroup to grafana and prints response
    WARNING: This will first delete all alerts in the AlertGroup before replacing them with the provided AlertGroup.

    :param alertjson - AlertGroup json generated by grafanalib
    :param folder - Folder to upload the AlertGroup into
    :param server - grafana server name
    :param api_key - grafana api key with read and write privileges
    '''
    groupName = json.loads(alertjson)['name']

    headers = {}
    if api_key:
        print("using bearer auth")
        headers['Authorization'] = f"Bearer {api_key}"

    if session_cookie:
        print("using session cookie")
        headers['Cookie'] = session_cookie

    print(f"deleting AlertGroup {groupName} in folder {folder}")
    r = requests.delete(f"http://{server}/api/ruler/grafana/api/v1/rules/{folder}/{groupName}", headers=headers, verify=verify)
    print(f"{r.status_code} - {r.content}")

    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    print(f"ensuring folder {folder} exists")
    r = requests.post(f"http://{server}/api/folders", data={"title": folder}, headers=headers)
    print(f"{r.status_code} - {r.content}")

    print(f"uploading AlertGroup {groupName} to folder {folder}")
    r = requests.post(f"http://{server}/api/ruler/grafana/api/v1/rules/{folder}", data=alertjson, headers=headers, verify=verify)
    # TODO: add error handling
    print(f"{r.status_code} - {r.content}")


grafana_api_key = getenv("eyJrIjoiS1ZjV0I2SWdlUm5lMnpYUVpzT2ZRUVpqMkM0QUVtYnIiLCJuIjoiTXlfa2V5IiwiaWQiOjF9")
grafana_server = getenv("localhost:3000")
grafana_cookie = getenv("GRAFANA_COOKIE")

# Generate an alert from the example
my_alergroup_json = get_alert_json(loader("example.alertgroup.py"))
upload_to_grafana(my_alergroup_json, "testfolder", grafana_server, grafana_api_key, grafana_cookie)
```

example.alertgroup.py  includes

```
from grafanalib.core import (
    AlertGroup,
    AlertRulev9,
    Target,
    AlertCondition,
    AlertExpression,
    GreaterThan,
    OP_AND,
    RTYPE_LAST,
    EXP_TYPE_CLASSIC,
    EXP_TYPE_REDUCE,
    EXP_TYPE_MATH
)

# An AlertGroup is one group contained in an alert folder.
alertgroup = AlertGroup(
    name="Production Alerts",
    # Each AlertRule forms a separate alert.
    rules=[
        # Alert rule using classic condition > 3
        AlertRulev9(
            # Each rule must have a unique title
            title="Alert for something 1",
            uid='alert1',
            # Several triggers can be used per alert
            condition='B',
            triggers=[
                # A target refId must be assigned, and exist only once per AlertRule.
                Target(
                    expr="from(bucket: \"sensors\")\n  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"remote_cpu\")\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"usage_system\")\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"cpu\"] == \"cpu-total\")\n  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)\n  |> yield(name: \"mean\")",
                    # Set datasource to name of your datasource
                    datasource="influxdb",
                    refId="A",
                ),
                AlertExpression(
                    refId="B",
                    expressionType=EXP_TYPE_CLASSIC,
                    expression='A',
                    conditions=[
                        AlertCondition(
                            evaluator=GreaterThan(3),
                            operator=OP_AND,
                            reducerType=RTYPE_LAST
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ],
            annotations={
                "summary": "The database is down",
                "runbook_url": "runbook-for-this-scenario.com/foo",
            },
            labels={
                "environment": "prod",
                "slack": "prod-alerts",
            },
            evaluateFor="3m",
        ),
        # Alert rule using reduce and Math
        AlertRulev9(
            # Each rule must have a unique title
            title="Alert for something 2",
            uid='alert2',
            condition='C',
            # Several triggers can be used per alert
            triggers=[
                # A target refId must be assigned, and exist only once per AlertRule.
                Target(
                    expr="from(bucket: \"sensors\")\n  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"remote_cpu\")\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"usage_system\")\n  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"cpu\"] == \"cpu-total\")\n  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)\n  |> yield(name: \"mean\")",
                    # Set datasource to name of your datasource
                    datasource="influxdb",
                    refId="A",
                ),
                AlertExpression(
                    refId="B",
                    expressionType=EXP_TYPE_REDUCE,
                    expression='A',
                    reduceFunction='mean',
                    reduceMode='dropNN'
                ),
                AlertExpression(
                    refId="C",
                    expressionType=EXP_TYPE_MATH,
                    expression='$B < 3'
                )
            ],
            annotations={
                "summary": "The database is down",
                "runbook_url": "runbook-for-this-scenario.com/foo",
            },
            labels={
                "environment": "prod",
                "slack": "prod-alerts",
            },
            evaluateFor="3m",
        )
    ]
)
```

I was expecting that after running this python script alert should be generated and automatically gets uploaded to my grafana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is incorrect use of [`getenv()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) in those lines:

```py
grafana_api_key = getenv("eyJrIjoiS1ZjV0I2SWdlUm5lMnpYUVpzT2ZRUVpqMkM0QUVtYnIiLCJuIjoiTXlfa2V5IiwiaWQiOjF9")
grafana_server = getenv("localhost:3000")
grafana_cookie = getenv("GRAFANA_COOKIE")
```

For example `getenv("localhost:3000")` tries to get environment variable with the name `localhost:3000`, doesn't find it and returns `None`.

It seems like you wanted to use something like `getenv("GRAFANA_HOST", "localhost:3000")`, and something similar with API key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for the suggestion that resolved my error. On running the scripts the errors which I am facing include 404 - b'message not found , 400-classification deserialization error 404 message not found can you please suggest me what should I do to resolve this thing??

Comment: @kartikGanotra, most likely you have incorrect path in your request. Consult appropriate [api documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/) on the matter.